# Erro NullPointerException ao executar projeto java maven

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

Criei um projeto Maven Java Application e somente criei um layout de uma tela.  Quando tento rodar, apresenta o erro de `NullPointer`, sendo que ainda não implementei nenhum código a não ser os próprios gerados pela IDE.

O que poderia ser a causa?

> ```
> --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ jSeguranca ---
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
> at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
> at br.com.jseguranca.Configuracao.initComponents(Configuracao.java:51)
> at br.com.jseguranca.Configuracao.<init>(Configuracao.java:18)
> at br.com.jseguranca.Configuracao$3.run(Configuracao.java:220)
> at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> BUILD SUCCESS
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> Total time: 3.121s
> Finished at: Tue Mar 07 18:13:30 BRT 2017
> Final Memory: 6M/245M
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Código gerado pelo NetBeans

```
public class Configuracao extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form Configuracao */
    public Configuracao() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtSigla = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtApp = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txtCnpj = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        btnAdd = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane4 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        listCnpj = new javax.swing.JList<>();
        btnSave = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(332, 470));
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/jseguranca/imagens/AM-Logomarca-312x82.png"))); // NOI18N

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jLabel2.setText("Empresa:");

        jLabel3.setText("Aplicativo:");

        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txtSigla);

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(txtApp);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        jLabel4.setText("CNPJ:");

        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(txtCnpj);

        btnAdd.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/jseguranca/imagens/add.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnAdd.setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(97, 27));
        btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnAddActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jScrollPane4.setViewportView(listCnpj);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane4)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnAdd)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(btnAdd)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 185, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        btnSave.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/jseguranca/imagens/save.png"))); // NOI18N
        btnSave.setText("Salvar");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnSaveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(btnSave, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                .addComponent(btnSave, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(14, 14, 14))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       


    }                                      

    private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                       

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Configuracao.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Configuracao.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Configuracao.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Configuracao.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Configuracao().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSave;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane4;
    private javax.swing.JList<String> listCnpj;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txtApp;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txtCnpj;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane txtSigla;
    // End of variables declaration
```

Comment: E o código jovem? só pelo erro não tem como sugerir solução.

Comment: Postei ai, porém eu não fiz nada de código. Tudo que esta ai foi gerado pelo NetBeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este trecho já lhe diz o motivo do erro:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:217) at
>   br.com.jseguranca.Configuracao.initComponents(Configuracao.java:51)

Na sua classe `Configuracao`, mais especificamente no método `initComponents`, está sendo passado um caminhode imagem nulo ou inválido. Por isso o erro estoura na classe `ImageIcon`.

E pelo código apresentado, o problema deve estar sendo originado nesta linha:

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/br/com/jseguranca/imagens/AM-Logomarca-312x82.png"))); // NOI18N
```

Reveja o caminho da imagem, provavelmente ela está apontando pro lugar errado.

Comment: Este caminho foi criado automático pela IDE. Usei a opção de icon do jLabel.

Comment: @JeremiasSantos pois é, mas se está dando nullpointer, ele está errado. Verifique se o caminho está correto e sete manualmente, se for o caso. Não confie demais na IDE pra fazer tudo, as vezes ela erra e dar uma tremenda dor de cabeça arrumar.

Comment: @JeremiasSantos uma dica, copie as linhas onde você setou imagem para algum componente, depois remova nas propriedades de cada um e rode o código e veja se o nullpointer continua.

Comment: Encontrado o Problema. Estava usando um projeto Maven ele estava buscando dentro de resources e as imagens não estavam. Não havia percebido, pois estava migrando um projeto já existente e deixe as imagens no pacote que ja estavam. Mudei para resources e funcionou perfeitamente.